# Erro ao acessar indice de dicionário

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

Eu criando um programa para ler de um arquivo `csv` um conjunto de coordenadas e armazenana-las em um objeto `DataFrame`. O código segue abaixo

```
df = pandas.read_csv(os.getcwd() + "/Coordinates.csv")
print(df["Longitude"])
```

O arquivo csv é o seguinte:

```
Longitude;Latitude
10;10
11.3;11.9
12.4;10.3
9.2;10.4
```

Ao rodar esse código o seguinte erro é apresentado:

```
  File "/home/bruno/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2522, in get_loc
 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in 
  pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in 
  pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  KeyError: 'longitude'
```

Ao imprimir do valor das colunas com obtenho:

`Index(['Longitude;Latitude'], dtype='object')`

Minha dúvida é se as colunas estão sendo lidas corretamente, por que o `keyError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O arquivo `.csv`foi gerado de forma incorreta. Usando `;` como separador o na realidade gera um único índice `Longitude;Latitude`.
O corereto é usar `,` como separador no arquivo de entrada. Dessa forma serão gerados dois índices: `longitude` e `latitude`